# Composer require patronbase/omnipay-redsys problem 1

Tags: php, composer-php, omnipay

```
  Problem 1
- patronbase/omnipay-redsys[dev-master, v3.1.0] require omnipay/common dev-address3-support -> found omnipay/common[dev-feat-httpdecorator, dev-feat-customer, dev-feat/symfony5, dev-fix-gateway-params, dev-feat-amountinteger, dev-future, dev-master, dev-revert-67-sf3-compat, dev-revert-184-feat-parameters, dev-feat-php8, dev-feat-psr18, dev-test/php72, v2.0.0, ..., 2.5.x-dev, v3.0-alpha.1, ..., 3.1.x-dev (alias of dev-master)] but it does not match the constraint.
- patronbase/omnipay-redsys 3.1.x-dev is an alias of patronbase/omnipay-redsys dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
- Root composer.json requires patronbase/omnipay-redsys ^3.1 -> satisfiable by patronbase/omnipay-redsys[v3.1.0, 3.1.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].
```

https://packagist.org/packages/patronbase/omnipay-redsys

I have this problem installing patronbase/omnipay-redsys, can someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This looks like a question better suited for https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

That package requires a non-existing branch of `omnipay/common`, so you need to use an older version of that package (like: `composer require omnipay/common 3.0.0`). Also, such an error should be reported to the maintainers of the package